upgrade next 12 to 13 - error in importing external packages
I'm currently upgrading an existing application from version 12 to 13. However, I'm encountering an error that says:
"The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax, so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script. Did you mean to build an EcmaScript Module ('output.module: true')?"

I've tried adding transpilePackages, but it seems that all the external packages and their dependencies need to be added as well.
Is there something that I've missed in the configuration?
I have just added reactStrictMode: true, in next.config.js
Note: I am not using App router.
